# Line Segments that end at the same point

Tags: trigonometry, 3d

Given the starting position and length of two line segments (P0, L0, P1, L2), find the configurations where both segments end at the same point. Both starting points can be anywhere in three dimensional space.

Comment: What is a configuration?  Two segments that have a common endpoint?  You have required that.  Are you asking where the endpoint can be, given the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine a sphere A with center $P_0$ and radius $L_0$ and a sphere B with center $P_1$ and radius $L_2$. The condition where the two line segments have the same end points is the same as the condition where the two spheres have at least one intersection. So, the condition will be

$|L_0-L_2| <= |\overrightarrow{P_0P_1}| <= L_0+L_2 $

Comment: what is the P0P1 notation? Is that the cross product of the 3D points or something else?

Comment: $|P_0P_1|$ means the distance between $P_0$ and $P_1$. I edited the equation to reflect this fact better.